# upload document with metadata in liferay

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, liferay-6

i am trying to upload document with metadata . simple file uploader portlet is working perfectly but when i try to attach metadata it sends request failed error

this is my code

```
public DLFileEntry upload(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)  throws Exception 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ServiceContext sc = new ServiceContext();
    Date date1 = (Date) request.getAttribute("efrom");
    Date date2 = (Date) request.getAttribute("efrom");
    String getTitle = request.getParameter("Title");
    String getDesc = request.getParameter("Description");
    String CKEditor = request.getParameter("CKE");

    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    long defaultRepoId = DLFolderConstants.getDataRepositoryId(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID);

    String rtfoutput = FileIO.readFromFile(tPath);

    File tempFile = new File(tPath);
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(tempFile);

    Folder folderName = DLAppLocalServiceUtil.getFolder(defaultRepoId, 0, "Folder Name");
    long folderId = folderName.getFolderId();
    long repositoryId = folderName.getRepositoryId();

    byte[] bytes = rtfoutput.getBytes();

    Map<String, Fields > fieldsMap = new HashMap<String, Fields >();
    Fields targetFields = new Fields();
    targetFields.put(new Field("Effective-To", date1));
    targetFields.put(new Field("Effective-From", date2));

    fieldsMap.put("", targetFields);

    DLFileEntry dlFileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(defaultRepoId, 0L, repositoryId, folderId, getTitle+".rtf", "RichTextFormat", getTitle, StringPool.BLANK, StringPool.BLANK, 0L,
            fieldsMap, tempFile, is, tempFile.getTotalSpace(), sc);

    return dlFileEntry;
}
```

i am not getting why this is saying request failed

date1 and date2 are the meta deta which i am trying to attact with document

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot simple add custom metadata. Every FileEntryType has a possible collections of metada-fields that is described by DDMStructure. However, you should first create/update the DDMStructure of your FileType and than put new MetaData. See for more details the source code of liferay and this post: http://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/13460906